# How to count and group items based on Date Range

Tags: sql, sorting, datetime, filtering

I have 3 tables that relate to each other. I combined the table using a WITH clause. I need to count the number of times a Serial Number appears for each user ID, but only during the timeframe the device was
assigned to them, as it will be reassigned to another
ID later.

The `Link_Date` and `Delink_Date` columns represent the time range a device was registered to a particular ID, and the `date_time` is the date of submission. I want to count the number of times `date_time` falls in the range of the `Link_Date` and `Delink_Date` for a particular ID.

This is the code I expected would work, but it does not work when the end date is NULL:

```
SELECT W.ID, COUNT(*) as COUNT
FROM W
WHERE W.Link_Date < W.date_time 
    AND  (W.Delink_Date =  NULL OR W.Delink_Date >  W.date_time)
GROUP By W.ID
```

[image: Whole Table Output]
[image: Expected Output]
[image: Current Output]

Comment: Can you edit your question and include your simple data as text not images

Comment: Posting images of technical information like code, sample data, and results, rather than formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored. You should use the edit link below the question post to replace the images with formatted text, or you're much less to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how `NULL` works: nothing is **ever** equal to `NULL`, even other `NULL` values. Therefore the `W.Delink_Date = NULL` expression is never true. You can use the `IS` operator (`W.Delink_Date IS NULL`) instead, but I'd write it like this:

```
SELECT W.ID, COUNT(*) as COUNT
FROM W
WHERE W.Link_Date <= W.date_time 
    AND W.date_time < coalesce(W.Delink_Date, '29991231')
GROUP By W.ID
```